# How to migrate to Ask Ubuntu?

Tags: support, migration

There's [a new question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/184780/building-a-file-in-linux) which is asking how to run `sudo ./some-script.sh` on Ubuntu. It's off-topic here, but Ask Ubuntu seems like a perfect fit.

However, when I go to flag it for a close vote, I don't get Ask Ubuntu as a migration option. There are Superuser and Serverfault, both of which *might* work, but I'm not sure which of those two would be better.

So, is there a way to flag for migration to Ask Ubuntu?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A moderator has to be involved in migrating questions to a site that isn't one of the five listed. Flagging the question for mods with a note saying which site is the best way to handle that.